# lmeNB Package: syntax problems

Tags: r, package, panel-data

I just learnt of the existence of the lmeNB package and given that I have positive count data data with overdispersion, it seemed right up my sleeve.
However, I cannot get it to work.

The syntax of the package is found [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/lmeNB/html/mle_ar1_fun.html)

I am trying to run a perfectly balanced panel with 37 individuals and 16 years per individual (my dataframe is ordered alfabetically and with increasing years, which I deem consistent with the description in the syntax.

`library(lmeNB)
mle.ar1.fun(abs_pb_t ~ RI1 + RA1 + abs_pb + cddom + cddom2, data=s.data, ID = p.data$ID, Vcode = p.data$Year`

Now I get the following error message:

`Error in`[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, upID == uniID[i], value = c("1--1", "1--2",  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In`[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, upID == uniID[i], value = c("1--1", "1--2",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In`[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, upID == uniID[i], value = c("1--1", "1--2",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

I think the problem identified in the warning causes the error but I have no single missing value in my data.frame and no perfect separation.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Simon

Comment: have you tried checking the data with `is.na`? I get errors like that when I think I've cleaned up a dataset, but there are artifacts left over (e.g., when I forget to use dropLevels)

Comment: Hey @Chris, I doublechecked and there are surely no NA in the s.data frame. I have been working with it for weeks and I would have bumped into trouble before. So I guess the problem is elsewhere